# Pc running, no display and mouse/keyboard

Tags: boot

I recently put a new pc together with the following hardware;

- ASRock 970 Pro3 R2.0
- MSI R7950 TF 3GD5/OC BE
- AMD FX-6300 Black Edition
- Crucial Ballistix Tactical BLT2C4G3D1608ET3LX0CEU
- Seasonic M12II 520W

The pc worked for about two hours but shut down already every half hour.

Now the pc is not working at all. When starting the fans work, but there is no display and keyboard and mouse are not working. There is no beeping sound either

Already rest the CMOS and tested without RAM, that did give a beeping sound.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds to me like your GPU has failed. With no display, you wouldn't know if the KB/Mouse didn't work, except for any lights on them that might show they are working (like caps lock or a light on the mouse). If those are working, your logic board sounds like it's fine. I would normally suggest testing with on-board video, but your board doesn't support it. Do you have another GPU that you can try? Do you have another PC you can test your GPU in? Those troubleshooting steps would help figure out which has failed. You can then contact the manufacturer (since you should still be under warranty), and get a replacement for failed components.

Comment: Forgot to mention, but the lights on the keyboard/mouse don't work, does that make it sound like the GPU or Motherboard is not working properly

Comment: With that added information it sounds like the motherboard. If the GPU had only failed, you should still have power to and input from the KB/Mouse. If the CPU failed, you would have a POST code probably immediately. If the RAM failed, you would have a POST code. You already stated you did get a POST code when you removed RAM.

I would suggest contacting the manufacturer of the motherboard (or the company you bought it from depending on the terms of the purchase) and attempt to RMA it after troubleshooting with them.